# WTL. Class derived from CEdit. Parent window does not react for EN_CHANGE

Tags: wtl, cedit

I need to handle EN_CHANGED.

```
COMMAND_HANDLER_EX(0, EN_CHANGE, OnEdit)
```

It works when I am using CEdit.

But it does not work when I am using CMyEdit.

```
class CMyEdit : public CWindowImpl<CMyEdit, CEdit>
```

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified 0 rather than a control ID as the first parameter of the command_handler_ex macro